# Java code execution in cloud

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cloud, ironworker

I've Genetic Algorithm implemented in Java, I want to write API/Service layer so that any developer can run their own fitness function for their own problem by some means to extend or to push their code to cloud and call some API method say init() and start() which acts in some async way & return the result on task completion.

I'm looking for something like http://www.iron.io/worker and most probably I'll put that code on Google's AppEngine.

Kindly guide me how can I achieve this or point me to any resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use IronWorker for this, the steps would most likely be something like this:

- Upload your algorithm as a worker to IronWorker
- Built your API to allow your users to call whichever function they need
- Your API would then queue up an IronWorker task for your genetics worker
- You mentioned you wanted it asynchronous, so once the worker completes, it could callback to an endpoint that your user provides (webhook) with the results (or it could wait and respond synchronously, depending on how long your algorithm takes to run)

Docs on IronWorker: http://dev.iron.io/worker/

Comment: If you want a running start for creating Java-based workers for IronWorker, take a look at this [Maven archetype in Github](https://github.com/brian-villanueva/ironworker-java-archetype) for such projects.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Modules feature (previously Backends) for GAE.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/

Combine it with other features like Task Queue (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/) and this may fit your requirements.